# What job was Adama being interviewed for?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

In Daybreak Part 1, we see Adama being interviewed and hooked up to a lie detector. What job was he being tested for?

Comment: Professional liar?

Comment: The wiki (and the episode summary online) just says "a civilian desk job". One assumes that it's in the Defence sector since that's his area of expertise